# How to get the hostname from emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I'd like to get something what `document.location.host` or `hostname` or `href` returns, but from inside emberjs. As the `currentpath` is just the router-defined path I cannot use that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of those things that you mentioned from inside Ember.